# php search result images show across and fill a CSS div

Tags: php, html, css

I'm using dreamweaver and php to return a list of images based on search critiera.
I have used Dreamweaver's repeat function and can get the images to repeat below each other (as below).

```
<table width="100" height="38" border="1"> 
<?php do { ?> 
<tr> 
<td width="38">
<img class='example' src="images/<?php echo $row_getresult['image_name']; ?>.png"/><br>       
</a></td></tr> 
<?php } while ($row_getamenityaccommodation = mysql_fetch_assoc($getamenityaccommodation)); 
?> 
</table>
```

How can I get the images to go across from each other within a CSS Div e.g. float:left; width:45%; so that if there are more images than what would fit in 45%, the images would continue onto a new line?

Would somehow 'printing' the array work?

Comment: Replace table with container of desired width and fill it with floated images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the table and replace with

```
<div style='width:45%'>
<?php do{ ?>
<img style='float:left;class='example' src="images/<?php echo $row_getresult['image_name']; ?>.png"/>
<?php } while ($row_getamenityaccommodation = mysql_fetch_assoc($getamenityaccommodation)); ?>
</div>
```

or for a more semantic version use a ul since you are showing a list of images.

```
<ul class='gallery'>
<?php do{ ?>
<li><img style='float:left;class='example' src="images/<?php echo $row_getresult['image_name']; ?>.png"/></li>
<?php } while ($row_getamenityaccommodation = mysql_fetch_assoc($getamenityaccommodation)); ?>
 </ul>
```

and in css

```
  ul.gallery {
       width: 45%;
       list-style: none;
       margin:0; padding:0;
  }

  ul.gallery li {
       float:left;
       padding: 5px;
  }
```